# Call gather dbms_stats for the schema in which a procedure is stored

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the below procedure in my DB schema ('MYSCHEMA').

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure
    IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('Start test');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user,'TEST');
    dbms_output.put_line('End test');
END my_procedure;
```

Table TEST does only exist in my schema. Is there any way to run this procedure from other schema and make it work without changing it to:

```
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('MYSCHEMA','TEST');
```

Details of my Oracle DB:

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DEFINER rights. Read before use [Invoker's Rights and Definer's Rights (AUTHID Property)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-41D23DE7-3C07-41CF-962B-F92B696594B5)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure
  AUTHID DEFINER  IS
BEGIN
...
```